# Gstreamer link udpsink and udpsrc in one element (C++)

Tags: python, c++, gstreamer

I have working pipeline and want to implement in C++. How can I link two elements in one element?

Pipeline example:

autoaudiosrc ! ...... ! rtpmp4apay ! **udpsink** host="" port=1234 **udpsrc** port=4321 ! ..... ! autoaudiosink

Here I need to combine *udpsink* and *udpsrc* to one element. Do I need to use *udpsink* as *g_object_set* to *udpsrc*?

Comment: What you want doesn't seem to make sense. What do you actually want to do?  How is the data supposet to flow?  Normally the first part of your pipeline would (till udpsink) would be running in one program.  The other part (starting with udpsrc) would be running in another program.

Comment: The main idea is to combine two pipelines in one. I have first pipeline to grab the mic output and send it via udpsink, the next pipeline is to receive with udpsrc and output it to speaker. All this need to be done in one machine. Basicaly what i need to do is VOIP.

Comment: My fully working pipeline is: gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! audioconvert ! webrtcdsp ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! rtpmp4apay ! **udpsink** host=192.168.1.100 port=1234 async=false      **udpsrc** port=1234 ! application/x-rtp,clock-rate=44100,config=40002410adca00  ! rtpmp4adepay ! avdec_aac ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! webrtcechoprobe ! audioconvert ! osxaudiosink

Comment: If you are running the command on a single device, why would you require UDP? Isn't UDP generally used for transporting across devices ?  And on the other hand, do you have any strict requirements with C++? In case your pipeline works fine on command-line, then you could use python and provide your complete pipeline to [Gst.parse_launch](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gst-1.0/functions.html#Gst.parse_launch). I think you could use this in your C++ and make it work as well.

Comment: I'm using in VOIP way, UDP is a must, because I need to send voice over network from one device and receive in another device. 
Background:
Pipeline in [A] device - > A sending voice to B, A receiving B voice
Pipeline in [B] device - > B sending voice to A, B receiving A voice

Comment: So you actually want 2 different pipelines running on those 2 devices. You don't need to combine them in any way, the first pipeline will send the data on udpsink to the host/port you select and the other pipeline will use udpsrc to receive that data.

Answer (score 0):

You pipeline description actually works.  "Linking two elements in one" doesn't make sense.  What is possible is that bins and pipelines can act as containers, so they can contain and represent several other elements.  udpsrc and udpsink in your pipeline description are *not linked*, because there is no exclamation mark.

In C/C++ you would call [gst_parse_launch()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch) with the same [pipeline description](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html#pipeline-description) as for gst-launch-1.0.  The docs for gst_parse_launch say "*If more than one toplevel element is specified by the pipeline_description, all elements are put into a GstPipeline, which then is returned.*"

Comment: @Monalisa did you try this? did it help?